# Storing and retrieving IXMLNodes in or from a TTreeview Items Data property

Tags: xml, delphi

Not sure if this is possible or not. I am using Delphi XE-5. i would like to 
store a XML node in a TreeView's Items Data property?

```
Node:= tvwItems.Items.AddObject(nil, RootNode.ChildNodes[I].ChildNodes[0].AttributeNodes[1].Text, RootNode.ChildNodes[I])
```

This gives me the following error

> [dcc32 Error] LtLiveApplication_Main.pas(88): E2010 Incompatible
>   types: 'Pointer' and 'IXMLNode'

So, if this can't be done, maybe I can the Integer value of teh Child Node casted to a TObject

```
Node:= tvwItems.Items.AddObject(nil, RootNode.ChildNodes[I].ChildNodes[0].AttributeNodes[1].Text,TObject(I));
```

Then in the TreeView OnClick event, I would like to get the node stored, and use it to fetch another node

Anyway, once I figure out how I should store it properly (IXMLNode or Integer), I need to retrieve it properly as well

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IXMLNode` is a reference counted interface.  You would have to type-cast it in order to get it into the `Data` property, and you would also have to manually increment the interface's reference count while the `TTreeNode` is alive and decrement it before the `TTreeNode` is destroyed:

```
var
  XmlNode: IXMLNode:
  Node: TTreeNode;
begin
  ...
  XmlNode := RootNode.ChildNodes[I];
  Node := tvwItems.Items.AddObject(nil, XmlNode.ChildNodes[0].AttributeNodes[1].Text, TCustomData(XmlNode));
  XmlNode._AddRef;
  ...
end;

procedure TMyForm.tvwItemsDeletion(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
var
  XmlNode: IXMLNode;
begin
  XmlNode := IXMLNode(Node.Data);
  XmlNode._Release;
end;

procedure TMyForm.tvwItemsClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
  XmlNode: IXMLNode;
begin
  Node := tvwItems.Selected;
  if Node <> nil then
  begin
    XmlNode := IXMLNode(Node.Data);
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Because of the extra reference counting needed, I would suggest deriving a new class from `TTreeNode` and give it an `IXMLNode` member, that way the compiler can handle the reference counting for you (no need to call `_AddRef()` and `_Release()` manually, and thus no need for the `OnDeletion` event handler):

```
type
  TMyTreeNode = class(TTreeNode)
  public
    XmlNode: IXMLNode;
  end;

procedure TMyForm.tvwItemsCreateNodeClass(Sender: TCustomTreeView; var NodeClass: TTreeNodeClass);
begin
  NodeClass := TMyTreeNode;
end;
```

```
var
  XmlNode: IXMLNode:
  Node: TTreeNode;
begin
  ...
  XmlNode := RootNode.ChildNodes[I];
  Node := tvwItems.Items.Add(nil, XmlNode.ChildNodes[0].AttributeNodes[1].Text);
  TMyTreeNode(Node).XmlNode := XmlNode;
  ...
end;

procedure TMyForm.tvwItemsClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
  XmlNode: IXMLNode;
begin
  Node := tvwItems.Selected;
  if Node <> nil then
  begin
    XmlNode := TMyTreeNode(Node).XmlNode;
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Awsome Answer!  Thank You very much!